# Why is Windows 10 file Explorer upper path bar all white, showing nothing, if Windows uses Dark mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, dark-mode

I set Windows 10 *Personalize > Colors > Choose your color* to Dark mode and now File Explorer path line is all white, and *Save as...* dialog, as from Paint, has same issue, *plus* buttons are all white.

I'm trying to switch to dark mode in everything, apps and windows.

Here is my File Explorer (AKA Windows Explorer)...
[image: Windows Explorer]

And here is *Save as...* (from Paint)...
[image: Save as...]

Comment: This is a badly done work in progress. I use Custom, Windows Dark, Apps Light to get a screen view that works in harmony.

Comment: @John, why not expalin how to do this as an *answer*, as it would be useful to others?

Comment: I think the OP wants Dark Mode and my comment provides Light Mode (which is how I work).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on my Windows 10 installation. Did you perform any modifications to system files, maybe to support custom themes?

Comment: No, I did not.  All I did was personalization > Colors > Choose your color > Dark, Trans effects off, Auto pick an accent.. OFF,

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. I went to settings > themes and changed the theme. And then that same toolbar became dark like everything else.